# Remove Audio in ReCaptcha?

Tags: audio, recaptcha

Haven't been able to do this yet! 
Anyone know a way to disable the audio feature in ReCaptcha?

Thanks!

Comment: Client specifically requires us to remove... Said they've seen this before.

Comment: I agree with @IDWMaster. Unless there is a **very good reason** for doing so, it should not be done, since it will prevent people with visual disabilities from accessing whatever is protected by reCAPTCHA.

Comment: @Soumya: you are right, there is no reason to remove it. BUT, that said, I bet not even ONE SINGLE PERSON with visual disabilities in the history of Internet has EVER passed an audio reCaptcha test... it is ugly and unusable, definitely an unexpected bad surprise, considering it comes from Google :(

Comment: reCaptcha audio is only in English, that's a really good reason.
A website that has no connection with that language, with customers that does not speak English, why would offer that option? It makes the problem worst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide the button:

```
#recaptcha_switch_audio { display: none; }
```

Comment: Any tips on how to do this ysrb?

Comment: #recaptcha_switch_audio { display: none; }