# Need to Remove Audio in ReCaptcha V2?

Tags: css, audio, recaptcha

Have tried multiple options as describe in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604844/remove-audio-in-recaptcha) but none of working.

```
#recaptcha-audio-button {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden!important;

}
#recaptcha_switch_audio { 
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
}
.rc-button-audio {
     display: none !important;
     visibility: hidden!important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do one thing!!! Can you share me the code for this, I mean right click on the button in Developer Console. and share that code on codepen. I may fix it from there dynamically

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather https://codepen.io/ashish-chaturvedi/pen/JjRpdOv

Comment: let me check :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Codepen have controls buttons HTML. let me know if you need more.. Actually Google Recaptcha load in an iframe

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather this is demo url https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Comment: Ya I straight away looked for Iframe itself :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226592/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-ashish-chaturvedi).